# count of subquery in doctrine - querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have simple query:

```
$this->qb->select('l.value')
        ->addSelect('count(l) AS cnt')
        ->addSelect('hour(l.time) AS date_hour')
        ->from(Logs::class, 'l')
        ->where('l.header = :header')
        ->groupBy('l.value')
        ->addGroupBy('date_hour')
        ->setParameter('header', 'someheader')
```

This code select 3 columns have one condition and two groupBy.

I want get **records count** of this query. Of course I dont want to download all records and check size of downloaded data.

**Question:** 
How to rebuild this query and get result from db as singleScalarValue()?

Comment: This query does not return single scalar result. I have to rebuild it but I dont know how

Comment: What u wanna count? Records, time or some value?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use (id column for count) here:

```
    ->addSelect('count(l) AS cnt')
```

Something like this, but if you show your Entity i can suggest right solution:

```
         $this->qb->select('l')
        ->addSelect('count(l.id) AS cnt')
        ->addSelect('hour(l.time) AS date_hour')
        ->from(Logs::class, 'l')
        ->where('l.header = :header')
        ->groupBy('l.value')
        ->addGroupBy('date_hour')
        ->setParameter('header', 'someheader')

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: How from selected 3 columns get one single scalar result? :P

Comment: Hmm.. i see.. probably custom query is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Since GROUP BY + COUNT + getSingleScalarResult does not seem to work together in DQL queries, I guess your best option is to count afterwards

```
$sub
    ->select('l.id')
    ->addSelect('l.value as hidden val')
    ->addSelect('hour(l.time) AS hidden date_hour')
    ->from(Logs::class, 'l')
    ->where('l.header = :header')
    ->groupBy('val')
    ->addGroupBy('date_hour')
    ->setParameter('header', 'someheader')
;

$subIds = array_column($sub->getQuery()->getResult(), 'id');
$count = count($subIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using COUNT() with GROUP BY will not return a single scalar value but a list of grouped results by your COUNT() value.
2. Counting with PHP the number results returned by Doctrine is not efficient if you have a lot of results.

You need to do a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( YourSubQuery );
```

that can be achieved with the Doctrine Paginator to count the number of returned results:

```
$paginator = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);

$count = count($paginator);
```